# In R how to insert in a model a variable that is a function of a binary variable?

Tags: r, variables, binary, statistics

I would like to know how to insert a variable that is a function of a binary variable.
I am sorry if this question does not sound clear, I am pretty new at R.
Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
Using multiple linear regression, my model consists of evaluating Y with predictors X1, X2, X3, X4 and X5 
X1, X2, X3 are normal (continuous?) variables
 and X4, X5 binary variables (take values 0 or 1)
So far my model in R looks like model<-lm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5)
I would now like to change X1 as a variable that is dependant on rather X4 takes value 0 or 1 (X1 as a function of X4) and would like to model Y with this change.
I have absolutely no clue how to do this, if someone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you man that you want an interaction? Our that you're trying to instrument for x1 with x4?  Or something else?

Comment: You probably will need a model like one of these: http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html Check for indicator function. If u need to recode x1 then ifelse could be an option ifelse(x1 > 0,x4,0) or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The "*" operator is used to build interactions in formulas. There's also an `interaction` function but it's only sensibly used when both contribution variables are categorical:

```
model<-lm( Y ~ X1*X4 + X2+X3+X5)
```

That will produce an extra interaction term that can be interpreted as the change in slope for X1 when X4 == 1. There will also be terms for the slope of X1 (when X4==0) and X4. The X4 term is to be interpreted as a "level-shift". It's always better use the `predict` function rather than trying to spend time decoding interactions. If X4 is not a factor variable you might need:

```
 model<-lm( Y ~ X1*factor(X4) + X2+X3+X5)
```